# Node.js and forever how to get uptime/starttime within the application

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever, uptime

I've a nodejs app running with forever `forever start service.js -w`. Now I want to check the uptime of the specific `service.js` app (and not the [system uptime](http://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_uptime)).

Is there a package or a possibility to easy check uptime or time since the latest start from within the `service.js` app when running?

ex: So that i can build a rest service showing the timestamp of the latest restart.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer the following approach without a global variable.

@neelsg your solution will force me to write the statement `startTime = new Date();` in app.js to make it globally reachable.

the simple module

> example/lastStart.js

```
var startTimestamp;

module.exports.getTimestamp = function () {
    if (!startTimestamp) {
        startTimestamp = new Date();
    }
    return startTimestamp;
};
```

initialize when the node app starts:

> app.js

```
require('./example/lastStart').getTimestamp();
```

and accessing the timestamp

> example/service

```
var lastStart = require("./lastStart");

exports.route = function (req, res) {
    res.json({started: lastStart.getTimestamp()});
}
```

Comment: Better option here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28706630/4398385

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if this will work for you, but why not just set a variable to the current time at the very start of the script?

```
var startTime = new Date();
```

That way, if you need to figure out how long it has been running, just compare that with the current time. This has the advantage of being entirely independent of [forever](/questions/tagged/forever) and anything else related to your environment