# How do I get the server uptime in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I get a server uptime in Node.js so I can output it by a command like;

```
if(commandCheck("/uptime")){
  Give server uptime;
}
```

Now I don't know how to calculate the uptime from the server's startup.

Comment: I realized it is unclear from your question, when you say "server", do you mean the uptime of the node server process, or the uptime of the system that the process is running on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do to get normal time format is;

```
String.prototype.toHHMMSS = function () {
    var sec_num = parseInt(this, 10); // don't forget the second param
    var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
    if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
    if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
    var time    = hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
    return time;
}

if(commandCheck("/uptime")){
    var time = process.uptime();
    var uptime = (time + "").toHHMMSS();
    console.log(uptime);
}
```

Comment: Nothing about this requires augmenting the string prototype.

Comment: Bottom line: `process.uptime();` - the rest is unnecessary.

Comment: are you sure your math for hours is correct? i think you need to subtract exceeded days:
`var hours = Math.floor( (seconds - (days*86000)) / 3600 );`

Comment: Note: Node.js allows for [os] system uptime as well `os.uptime()`

Answer (score 25):

You can use [`process.uptime()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_uptime). Just call that to get the number of seconds since `node` was started.

```
function format(seconds){
  function pad(s){
    return (s < 10 ? '0' : '') + s;
  }
  var hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60*60));
  var minutes = Math.floor(seconds % (60*60) / 60);
  var seconds = Math.floor(seconds % 60);

  return pad(hours) + ':' + pad(minutes) + ':' + pad(seconds);
}

var uptime = process.uptime();
console.log(format(uptime));
```

Comment: Does this function has a time format so i can make use of hh:mm:ss

Comment: Note: Node.js allows for [os] system uptime as well `os.uptime()`

Answer (score 21):

To get process's uptime in seconds

```
    console.log(process.uptime())
```

To get OS uptime in seconds

```
    console.log(require('os').uptime())
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. Returns 171755 seconds just after app start

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Server and process uptime.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is a *nix server, you can use the `uptime` shell command using `child_process`:

```
var child = require('child_process');
child.exec('uptime', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

If you want to format that value differently or pass it through somewhere else, it should be trivial to do so.

EDIT: The definition of uptime seems a little unclear. This solution will tell the user how long the device has been powered on for, which may or may not be what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're talking about an HTTP server, an actual machine (or VPS) or just a Node app in general. Here's an example for an `http` server in Node though.

Store the time when your server starts by getting `Date.now()` inside the `listen` callback. And then you can calculate uptime by subtracting this value from `Date.now()` at another point in time.

```
var http = require('http');

var startTime;

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Uptime: ' + (Date.now() - startTime) + 'ms');
});

server.listen(3000, function () {
    startTime = Date.now();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the unix uptime in ms syncronously:

```
const fs= require("fs");

function getSysUptime(){

     return parseFloat(fs.readFileSync("/proc/uptime", { 
       "encoding": "utf8" 
     }).split(" ")[0])*1000;

}

console.log(getSysUptime());
```