# Is there any NodeJs class/function which is similar to Environment.TickCount on c#?

Tags: node.js

This code is running on c#

```cs
int x = Environment.TickCount;
```

[docs for Environment.TickCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.tickcount?view=netcore-3.1)

> Gets the number of milliseconds elapsed since the system started. TickCount cycles between Int32.MinValue, which is a negative number, and Int32.MaxValue once every 49.8 days.

> TickCount will increment from Zero to (2147483647) for approximately 24.9 days, then jump back to (-2147483648), which is a negative number, then increment back to zero during the next 24.9 days.

> We can use `int result = Environment.TickCount & Int32.MaxValue;` to make it rotate between (0) and (2147483647) for every 24.9 days

I want an equivalent method in NodeJS, which would yield the same result.

I made a search on NodeJS [npmjs](https://npmjs.com) but didn't find similar function

Comment: Maybe you should add what `Environment.TickCount` provides because the folks with only NodeJS knowledge may be able to help you if you mention what is it that exactly you need.

Comment: @RaghavGarg i will edit the question

Comment: as per @RaghavGarg comment what TickCount doing the information you provide is not clear

Comment: @ash i edit the question please refresh the page

Comment: I'm don't have knowledge of C# the quote you provide is not clear what actually TickCount doing

Comment: ok its start from -2147483648 to 2147483647 in 49.8 days.
and then back towards  
that's mean -2147483648 - 1000 OR -1200 every second depend on the period 49.8 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.uptime()` is the closest method to what you need which

> Returns the system uptime in number of seconds

[NodeJS docs](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_uptime)

But this is a valid question that what will be the max limit for the above method.?

In NodeJS the max safe integer is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` that is `9007199254740991`. Which is basically `289583309.373 years`. So I guess we will have to assume this as the max value for said method.

If you want the functionality as of c#'s `TickCount`, you will need to create your own custom method, maybe something like given below:

```js
// this method will cycle between 0 and 2147483647
function TickCount() {
    const miliseconds_elapsed = os.uptime() * 1000; // convert the time in miliseconds
    return miliseconds_elapsed % 2147483647;
}

// this method will cycle between -2147483648 to 2147483647
// note: it will not start from 0
function TickCount() {
    const miliseconds_elapsed = os.uptime() * 1000; // convert the time in miliseconds
    return (miliseconds_elapsed % 4294967296) - 2147483648;
}

// this method will cycle between -2147483648 to 2147483647
// note: it will start from 0 goes to 2147483647 
// then comes back to -2147483648 and starts the cycle
function TickCount() {
    const miliseconds_elapsed = os.uptime() * 1000; // convert the time in miliseconds
    if (miliseconds_elapsed <= 2147483647) {
        return miliseconds_elapsed;
    }
    return ((miliseconds_elapsed - 2147483648) % 4294967296) - 2147483648;
}
```

Comment: can you make it cycle between 2147483647 to -2147483648

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.tickcount?view=netcore-3.1) say `Environment.TickCount` is an integer that "contains the amount of time in milliseconds that has passed since the last time the computer was started".

When searching for that I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705009/how-do-i-get-the-server-uptime-in-node-js) and the answers suggest to use `process.uptime()` or`os.uptime()`

Comment: ok but that's not cycles between Min and Max value of In32